# Do mutexes block ALL threads at any point?

Tags: linux, multithreading, concurrency

In Linux, say I have code with 100 threads. 5 of those threads compete over a shared resource protected by a mutex. I know that when the critical section is actually being run, only the 5 threads are subject to having their execution stopped if they try to obtain the lock and the other 95 threads will be running without issues.

My question is is there any point at which those other 95 threads' execution will be paused or affected, ie when the mutex/kernel/whatever is determining which threads are blocked on the mutex and which thread should get the lock, and which threads should be able to run because their not asking for the lock, etc

Comment: Maybe if they too have a mutex over which they compete?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, other threads are not affected.

The kernel doesn't *ask* which threads are affected by the lock. Each thread *tells* the kernel when it tries to acquire the lock.

When threads do that, they go to sleep and get into a special wake-up queue associated with the lock.

Threads that don't use the lock won't get into the same queue as those that do, so their blocking behavior is unrelated.

Comment: Perhaps to help explain this, the only threads that will stop their work (not all threads have to be doing the same sort of work), are the ones that need to acquire the particular lock that is being held.  The goal is to acquire the lock, do whatever you need (access a shared variable, increment a counter, whatever), then let go of the lock as quickly as possible so another thread can acquire it.